# Can't serialize GeoJson coordinates in .Net Core controller

Tags: asp.net-core, geojson, .net-6.0, system.text.json, nettopologysuite

I have a .net 6 API project that exports FeatureCollections. I'm using 'NetTopologySuite.IO.GeoJSON' version 2.0.4, and have a public API call like:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ExportGeoJSON()
{
    GeoJSON.Net.Feature.FeatureCollection ret = new GeoJSON.Net.Feature.FeatureCollection();
    const double lat = -73.697913;
    const double lon = 50.659193;
    GeoJSON.Net.Geometry.Position coord = new GeoJSON.Net.Geometry.Position(lat, lon);
    GeoJSON.Net.Geometry.Point pt = new GeoJSON.Net.Geometry.Point(coord);
    GeoJSON.Net.Feature.Feature feat = new GeoJSON.Net.Feature.Feature(pt, null, Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
    ret.Features.Add(feat);
    return Ok(ret);
}
```

When i call this, i get back only:

```
{
  "Type": "FeatureCollection",
  "Features": [
    {
      "Type": "Feature",
      "Id": "465f399d-b45c-47ed-b9e6-f395cd86b84b",
      "Geometry": {
        "Type": "Point"
      }
    },...
```

Ok, i look around and find out about GeoJSON4STJ https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/NetTopologySuite.IO.GeoJSON , so I put that into my Startup:

```
    services.AddControllers()
        .AddJsonOptions(opts =>
        {
            opts.JsonSerializerOptions.DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull;    
            opts.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
            opts.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());   
            opts.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new NetTopologySuite.IO.Converters.GeoJsonConverterFactory());    
        });
```

and run it again, but no change at all.  Exactly the same response.  Am i missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are mixing libraries. `NetTopologySuite.IO.GeoJSON` (and `NetTopologySuite.IO.GeoJSON4STJ`) works with features from `NetTopologySuite.Features` package not from `GeoJSON.Net`.

Comment: Ah, that must be it.  didn't realize they were incompatible, but of course that makes sense!